# Showing that a covering map from a path connected space to a simply connected space is a homeomorpism.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, connectedness, covering-spaces

> Let $p : E \to B$ be a covering map with $E$ path connected and $B$
>   simply connected. Then $p$ is a homeomorphism.

**My approach :** Let $p(e_0)=b_0.$ Since $E$ is path connected, the lifting correspondence $\phi : \pi_1(B,b_0) \to p^{-1}(b_0)$ is surjective. But since $B$ is simply connected, $\pi_1(B,b_0)=\{e\}.$ Thus $|p^{-1}(b_0)|=1.$ Next, connectedness of $B$ implies that $|p^{-1}(b)|=1 \; \forall \; b \in B.$

Thus every $b \in B$ has an evenly covered neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)=V$ for some open neighborhood of $e_0$ and $p|_U : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism.

---

I think I am close to finishing the proof but I am stuck here. What is the idea to complete this proof?

Comment: I don't understand what a surjection from $\pi_1(B)$ to a fiber of $p$ is, and I don't understand how you got it.

Comment: You proved that $p$ is a bijective local homeomorphism: what more could you want ?

Comment: @AndresMejia I actually used **Theorem 54.4** of Munkres there. It is as follows "Let $p : E \to B $ is a covering map and $p(e_0)=b_0$. If $E$ is path connected, then the lifting correspondence $\phi : \pi (B,b_0) \to p^{-1}(b_0)$ is surjective. If $E$ is simply connected then it is bijective."

Comment: ahh I understand. I didn't realize that was the "correspondence" map. Maybe you should specify what $\phi$ is.

Comment: @AndresMejia My bad. I'll add this in OP now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the induced map $p_*:\pi_1(E) \to (B)$ will be injective, so $\pi_1(E)$ also needs to be trivial (making $E$ simply connected as well.)

Since $E$ is path connected, suppose that $|p^{-1}(b)|>1$, and take  a path between two points: $\alpha:a \mapsto b$. $p \circ \alpha$ is a loop in $B$, $\dots$

---

Using the theorem in your question, you have injectivity. You should show that a local homeomorphism is open (maps open sets to open sets) and then you will have the result. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826878/show-that-every-local-homeomorphism-is-continuous-and-open-therefore-bijective-l) for a hint.