# Every local homeomorphism is an open map (Goldblatt's Topoi)

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory, open-map

This is at the top of page 97.

> A **sheaf** is a bundle with some additional topological structure.  Let $I$ be a topological space, with $\Theta$ its collection of open sets.  A **sheaf** over $I$ is a pair $(A, p)$ where $A$ is a topological space $p : A \to I$ is a continuous map that is a local homeomorphism.  This means that each point $x \in A$ has an open neighborhood $U$ in $A$ that is mapped homeomorphically by $p$ onto $p(U)$, and the latter is open in $I$.  The category $\textbf{Top}(I)$ of sheaves over $I$ has such pairs $(A, p)$ a objects, and as arrows $k:(A, p) \to (B, q)$ the *continuous* maps $k : A \to B$ such that $q\circ k = p$ commutes.   **Such $k$ is in fact an open map (as is a local homeomorphism) and in particular $\text{Im} \ k = k(A)$ will be an open subset of $B$.**

Here is my proof attempt.

*A local homeomorphism $f: A \to I$ is an open map.*

**Proof.**
Let $U \subset A$ be open.  Then for each $x \in U, \exists \ V_x \subset A$ which is open and such that $g = f|_{V_x} : V_x \simeq f(V_x)$ is a homeomorphism.  Thus $V_x \cap U = $ an open set in $V_x$ and so $g(V_x \cap U) = g(V_x) \cap g(U)$ is open in $g(V_x)$.

Here I'm not sure whether unioning over $x$ would get us there.

Let's just focus on the local homeomorphism and I will make another question for the map $k$ if I need to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that every local homeomorphism is continuous and open therefore bijective local homeomorphism is a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826878/show-that-every-local-homeomorphism-is-continuous-and-open-therefore-bijective-l)

Comment: @ArnaudD. nope because of bijectivity added there.  And I read the answers there, and still had the same question.

Comment: The first part is to show that a local homeomorphism is open, without any assumption of bijectivity.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I am more happy with the answer below than any answer provided in that linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in f(U)$. You want to find an open neighborhood of $y$ which is contained inside $f(U)$. Let $x\in U$ with $f(x) = y$. Using the local homeomorphism property, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f|V$ is a homeomorphism of $V$ onto $f(V)$. Then $f|V$ is an open map; since $V \cap U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $V$, then $f(V \cap U)$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ which is contained in $f(U)$.

Comment: so, since $f\vert_V$ is an open map because it is a homeomorphism from $V$ to $f(V)$, the image of $V\cap U$ is open because it's $f(U\cap V)=f\vert_V(U)$. Therefore $f(U\cap V)\subset f(U)$ and this shows that $f(U)$ is open because it is neghbourhood of each of its points.

Comment: @Vajra yes, it looks like you got it.

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the last step. Let's call $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{Y})$ the topology space on Y, and $(V,\mathcal{T}_{V})$ the subspace on V induced by $\mathcal{T}_{Y}$. According to my understanding, local homomorphism only implies that $f(U\bigcap V)$ is open in$(V,\mathcal{T}_{V})$. But how do we know that an open set in $(V,\mathcal{T}_{V})$ must be an open set in $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{Y})$?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it because local homeomorphism maps an open neighborhood V in X onto an open set $f(V)$ in Y. So every open set in $(V,\mathcal{T}_{V})$ is still open in $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{Y})$.

Comment: @JakeZHANGShiyu that’s correct.